# Check if Storage Resource Exists

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am wondering if the following will cover all cases where there was no resource at the request's path before:

```
allow write: if resource == null;
```

This should only allow files to be created but not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - that is all you need to prevent editing/overwriting files. Note that it will also prevent any deletions, if you want to allow deletions you'd need to add in a condition something like:

```
allow write: if (resource == null || request.resource == null);
```

I'm sure you've already found the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files) (*subsection **Resource Evaluation***) on this stuff... but I'll include a [link here to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50919954/8026947) by Google's own Frank van Puffelen that acts as a good reference.